# How to remove rows with dates which are lower than a specific date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
             rate  year  month  week  day   pct_day
1973-01-02   8.02  1973      1     1    2       NaN
1973-01-03   8.02  1973      1     1    3  0.000000
1973-01-04   8.00  1973      1     1    4 -0.002494
1973-01-05   8.01  1973      1     1    5  0.001250
1973-01-08   8.00  1973      1     2    8 -0.001248
          ...   ...    ...   ...  ...       ...
2020-05-22  75.99  2020      5    21   22  0.004760
2020-05-26  75.43  2020      5    22   26 -0.007369
2020-05-27  75.88  2020      5    22   27  0.005966
2020-05-28  75.67  2020      5    22   28 -0.002768
2020-05-29  75.59  2020      5    22   29 -0.001057
```

How can i remove dates which are lower than `1998-09-09`. To do this i have done this:

```
date1 = date.datetime(2008, 1, 1)
date1 = date1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data[pd.to_datetime(data.index) >= pd.to_datetime('date1')]
```

but after the last line of code i am getting :

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: date1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data[pd.to_datetime(data.index) >= pd.to_datetime('date1')]
```

should be something like

```
data[pd.to_datetime(data.index) >= pd.to_datetime(date1)]
```

as date1 is a variable you've defined and you are calling it as a string.

Alternatively, pandas has a query system built in that allows you to do things like

```
data_less_than_data = data.query("index >= 1998-09-09")
```

my syntax for querying the index might be off but that's the basic idea.

Comment: query is neat!!

Answer (score 2):

date1 is a string. Instead try passing `pd.to_datetime(date1)` or just `pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])` if you create a column called `date1`